# Why does MySQL query read integer column as byte array in VB.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, .net-3.5, integer, arrays

I've got a simple MySQL table, which contains an "Age" column with integer and null values.

```
    Customers
    +--------------+--------------+ .... +------------+
    |    Name      |   Location   |      |     Age    |
    +--------------+--------------+ .... +------------+
    |   Murphy     |     US       |      |      23    |
    |   Pierre     |     France   |      |      42    |
    |   Rafael     |     Spain    |      |     null   |
    |   Paulo      |     Italy    |      |      21    |
    +--------------+--------------+ .... +------------+
```

Name and Location are type `varChar` and Age is type `int`.

However when I attempt to read from it in my VB.net code...

```
Dim connStr as string = Session("connectionString") 'My Connection String'
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers;"
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
conn.Open()
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql , conn)
Dim ds as new dataset
da.Fill(ds)
```

... the Age column in the dataset `ds` has `System.Byte[]` in every cell instead of the integer value.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried assigning this to a datatable instead of a dataset?

Comment: Try using a select like this, to see if it works. SELECT NAme,Location,IFNULL(Age,0) AS Age FROM Customers;

Comment: @KayNelson Yeah IFNULL(Age,0) seems to do it. Thanks. Not sure why though.

Comment: Can i add it as a answer? I think the dataset recognises the null value and changes the datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make sure that Age column only returns integer values.

Change your select to

```
SELECT Name,Location,IFNULL(Age,0) AS Age FROM Customers;
```

Another check, does your dataset allow dbnull? There is a property you can change. Maybe give that a try also with your inital `SELECT * FROM Customers;`